# mongoose update on array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

im trying to make an update on my bd, but the problem is that i dont have an id per object, the only thing i can identify by its the "description" property.
I want to update that property value but first i have to find it and update it as well, this is the json

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "637c1064a2f047f5ab75ac42"
  },
  "title": "this is a list",
  "todo": [
    {
      "completed": false,
      "description": "a normal task"
    },
    {
      "completed": false,
      "description": "this is another task"
    },
    {
      "completed": false,
      "description": "another task"
    }
  ],
  "username": "lucas",
  "__v": 3
}
```

This is what im trying to do, im trying to update the property description with a new description, but first i have to find the same element that matches with whats in the body.

```
  List.findOneAndUpdate(
        {todo: {description: req.body.description}},// trying to find it here
        {$set:{todo : {description: req.body.newDescription}}}, //trying to change it here
        function(err, response) {
            console.log(err,response)
          }
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple mistakes:

First one is you are using `{todo: {description: req.body.description}}` to find the object. In this way, mongo tries to compare using the whole object, that means only will return a match if `todo` is equal to `description: value`. But `todo` is an array and it contains objects.

Take a look to the [dot notation docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

The second part is to use [positional operator `$`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). With `$` you can tell mongo "get the element you have found in the prevous stage and update with the new value".

So you can try this query:

```
List.findOneAndUpdate({
  "todo.description": req.body.description
},
{
  "$set": {
    "todo.$.description": req.body.newDescription
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/N2t8Td96jjX)

Comment: Thanks for that but doesnt work, idk why, im sending this: {
   "title": "this is a list",
    "completed": false,
    "description": "this is another task",
    "newDescription" : "updated task",
   "username": "lucas"
}

Comment: i try with findOneAndUpdate and updateOne

Comment: now works but with a function as third parameter, but why?

Comment: I think you have to try something [like this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qkFGL6uzUqT)

Comment: Do you use `await`? Otherwise you can get the data in the callback (the function)

Comment: it was the await, sorry and thanks for taking the time :)